# Can we get a custom "suspected AI abuse" deletion reason in review queues?

Tags: feature-request, answers, deleted-answers, review, generative-ai

Recently we decisively [decided to ban ChatGPT](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12383/44723). It would be welcome to indicate to other users in the review queues that we suspect AI-Chatbot abuse using a template comment.

Comment: There is no need for a comment. Just flag the post for moderator attention.

Comment: FYI Moderators can create up to three community specific *close* reason (all of which are in use) but we have no options to create custom deletion reasons. Therefore this would need to be implemented by SE itself.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389353/526695 feature-request on meta.