# Do we want a banner/help page about AI policy?

Tags: discussion, answers, policy, help-center, generative-ai

Per a [previous discussion](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12383/4563), “generative AI” is banned on this site.

Per a [recent site-wide announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/190917), we can request a banner in the answer box stating this policy, and linking to a new Help page that would be created for this purpose.

As shown in that announcement, the banner would look something like this (but in our color scheme):

> [image: Image showing the answer field, in focus, with a banner saying "Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow. Learn more"]

The text of the banner is not customizable, but the text of the Help page that the Learn more link directs to is.

Thus, we need a consensus on

1. Do we want this banner?
2. Do we want a Help page, and if so, what should it say?

It’s not clear to me that a banner is necessary for the Help page—Stack Overflow, for example, already had the Help page before the banner existed. So I believe that an answer of “no banner, but the Help page would be good and should say XYZ,” is a valid option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### A banner is not needed right now. Help page yes.

I've got a couple of kids. I learned very quickly that if you tell a kid not to do something, that's the thing they're going to do. *Especially* if they weren't even going to think about doing the thing until you told them. *We do not have a problem with AI content right now*. I can count on one hand the posts I knew or suspected of being AI generated. By putting a banner on the answer box, we're drawing attention to a problem that we don't have, pointing out the possibility of using AI to people who weren't thinking about using AI until we told them. **No banner necessary for now**.

However, AI generated content has been posted before, and it probably will be posted again. I think having a help page [like the one on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy) would be a helpful resource as a "company official" position on use of AI. Our in-house meta discussion is, of course, sufficient, but an official help page is less vulnerable to "that's just like your opinion man" arguments. **Yes help page**.

Comment: It is unfortunate that they don't enable the banner only when you copy a large chunk of characters. I wanted this, but the current banner implementation is so crude.

Comment: @AkixkisuisonStrike That’s a pretty excellent suggestion to make to SE though, that’d be a pretty good feature.

Comment: While I agree with the text, I think this would be better titled “banner not yet”. I can see separate arguments for a hard “no” position, and it will be easier to revisit later if we don’t conflate them.

Comment: @AkixkisuisonStrike: I think that was something that users have proposed before. It's not a bad idea, IMO, though it has some issues (e.g. users might not notice it after they've pasted something in, and users who *haven't* used ChatGPT/genAI may feel like they're getting in trouble for something they haven't done).